# Regex for field that allows numbers and spaces

Tags: regex

I want that the text field only accept numeric values and spaces.
What is regular expression for this?
I was trying with `\d+$`
Thanks

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This one should work :

```
[0-9 ]+
```

Comment: **OR also use with start and end string**  `^[\d\s]+$`

Answer (score 20):

`^` for the begining of string.
`[\d ]*` for any combination of this symbols.
`$` for end of string.

`^[\d ]*$`

Comment: I wouldn't consider a string with 0 occurrences of numeric values/spaces a string consisting of numeric values/spaces.

Comment: <text field only accept numeric values and spaces>. That means it does not accept any symbol besides numeric values and spaces. That means that empty string does not violate the condition

Comment: for example if you need to validate user input, you should not write an error, when user have not started to write anything or just deleted all he wrote.

Comment: Huh? The text field could be empty. If the user hit submit and the text box was empty, your regex would match the empty string.

Comment: How do you know in what context he is using this in? It could be for form validation after Submit has already been clicked.

Comment: and could be not. so my assumption is as true as yours.

Answer (score 6):

You're going to want to use `[0-9 ]+`

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
/^[0-9\s]*$/
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match only the numbers, use:

> `(\b\d+)/g` or `(\b[0-9]+)/g`

where:
`\b` will match borders
`\d` or `[0-9]` match numbers
`+` will match 1 or more times `\d` (or `[0-9]`)
`/g` turns on global mode, to match the regex many times

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression matches numbers with spaces, numbers without spaces, but not the spaces after all numbers

```
(\s*[0-9]+)+
```