# regex for field that accepts spaces OR not AND numeric OR numeric with space

Tags: regex

I want a text field that accept numeric values OR just spaces and not number WITH space. What is the regular expression for this. Please help... Thanks in advance.

eg: 
valid = '456631', '' , ' '  AND '123 1232' = invalid

Comment: Not sure you made it much clearer - "numeric value with spaces and not number WITH space"?

Comment: Well, hit the wrong link :) Really, was not going to reopen the question. Still consider it a dupe of [Regex for field that allows numbers and spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973206/regex-for-field-that-allows-numbers-and-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

use following regex :

```
^[\d ]+$
```

Comment: This would match `11\n21` while `\n` isn't a space

Comment: Yes, @ThomasAyoub, You are right, if use this for textarea. I have corrected my answer above. Thank you.

Comment: @Rohit Goyani - sorry for the late reply. Anyhow i have implemented this, i will let u know by EOD if it's working or not. Thanku so much.

Comment: @CodingOwl, whats going on?