# Check if a string contains only digits and white space in java Android

Tags: java, android

I know this is a common way to ask but I just want to include white space when checking digits number, so I have this string

```
6031 3100 3440 0189 000
```

So now I want to check that value if it is contains just only the number

*I came up with this solution*

```
String Cardresult = edtCashCard.getText().toString();
if (Cardresult.matches("[0-9]+")){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good Job the strings are numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
else{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error the string contains character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But now I know there's white space in the variable and based on the first condition, even though your variable contains numbers but since there's white space it does not count as a number it counts as string, and now I want to consider white space as a number to trigger to the first condition, is there anything that can I do with this? It very helpful me a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973206/regex-for-field-that-allows-numbers-and-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ADM suggested in comment you can update your regex `[0-9]+` with below

```
[0-9 ]+
```

so it look like

```
 String Cardresult = edtCashCard.getText().toString();
    if (Cardresult.matches("[0-9 ]+")){
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Good Job the strings are numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
    }
    else{
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error the string contains character", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks `[0-9 ]` this is in my mind in the first place but I didn't try.

Comment: How on earth is trim going to work?

Comment: @ScaryWombat sry that was my bad, code updated plz check.... this may work

Comment: `Cardresult.replace(" ","");` - this also will not work, Strings are immutable.